# How to detect command key as a modifier in a glut program running on a mac?

Tags: macos, opengl, glut, keyboard-events

I am developing a GLUT program on a mac. Mac's seem to pass modifiers through GLUT in a funny way. Alt and control keys are not captured by glutGetModifiers() instead they're translated into the button int. The command key doesn't seem to be captured by either glutGetModifiers() or the button int. Also, it doesn't show up as a key in my glutKeyboardFunc(...).

Is there any way to capture/detect the command (apple) key in GLUT?

Comment: Which GLUT implementation are you using?

Comment: OpenGL on the mac is a lot easier if you use Cocoa.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to have something similar to how Qt handles the command key. It's treated like the windows control key. That way my app on mac would function the *same* as on windows. I don't want to  use cocoa because I'd still like to be able to run it on PC/linux if  it comes down to that. I used Qt before but it's really overkill for my small app.

I'm using whatever GLUT is implemented in the mac framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glutGetModifiers`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/glutGetModifiers.3.html) only detects CTRL, ALT and SHIFT, not the `⌘` key.

The only way I know how to do this is to use [Carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466294/getting-keyboard-state-using-getkeys-function),

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

KeyMap keyStates ;
bool IS_KEYDOWN( uint16_t vKey )
{
  uint8_t index = vKey / 32 ;
  uint8_t shift = vKey % 32 ;
  return keyStates[index].bigEndianValue & (1 << shift) ;
}

void checkInput()
{
  // This grabs all key states, then checks if you were holding down ⌘ or not
  GetKeys(keyStates) ;
  if( IS_KEYDOWN( kVK_Command ) )
    puts( "⌘" ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the Carbon solution is better in some cases, one may also directly patch and replace the GLUT framework on mac os x to support the command key. [This patch](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=3659) catches the command key and defines a respective modifier mask `GLUT_ACTIVE_COMMAND`.