# Getting keyboard state using GetKeys function

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, core-foundation

Does anyone know how to get any key state (pressed or no) by GetKeys function?
In other words how to handle this function:

```
bool result = isPressed(kVK_LeftArrow);
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `KeyMap` type is an array of integers but its real layout is a series of bits, one per key code.  The bit number for a particular key is *one less than* the virtual key code.

Since bit-shifting isn't legal for very large values (e.g. you can't just ask the compiler to shift 74 bits), the `KeyMap` type is broken into 4 parts.  You need to take the virtual key code's bit number and integer-divide by 32 to find the correct integer for the bit; then take the remainder to figure out which bit should be set.

So, try this:

```
uint16_t vKey = kVK_LeftArrow;
uint8_t index = (vKey - 1) / 32;
uint8_t shift = ((vKey - 1) % 32);
KeyMap keyStates;
GetKeys(keyStates);
if (keyStates[index] & (1 << shift))
{
    // left arrow key is down
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work because keyStates[kVK_LeftArrow - 1] is a struct and cant be assumed as bool, also KeyMap defined as typedef BigEndianUInt32 KeyMap[4]; and the index kVK_LeftArrow - 1 is bigger than 4.

Comment: True...I didn't state that correctly.  I've updated my answer to describe the way the structure should be used.  I think my math is correct; maybe I'm off by 1 somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  You know this really is undocumented anywhere.  I couldn't find a source page on developer.apple.com. Anyway, for `kVK_ANSI_W` etc, (which are NOT in ASCII order by the way), you _don't_ need to -1 from vKey (it will be wrong).

Comment: This did not compile for me, i had to changed it to:   if ((keyStates[index].bigEndianValue & (1 << shift)))

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on this madness.

Comment: (keyStates[index] & (1UL << shift))